# CanCan authorize by id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I have a many to many relationship in rails, a user has and belongs to many user_types and vice versa.  Then user_type has many roles.

Example table for roles_fruits table:

> role_id: 1, fruit_id: 6

Example for roles table:

> id: 1,  name: Bannana Worker

Example table for users:

> id: 1, user_name: employee143

Example for fruits table:

> id: 6, name: bananna

In the model

## user.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
```

## roles.rb

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

Now, what I am trying to accomplish is to allow a user that has the role of "Bannana Worker" (id 1) to be able to get to it and those without it, not to be able to get into it.

### Pseudocode would look something like this:

if user.roles contains fruit id then can :manage, fruit

How can I accomplish this with cancan and if it isn't possible, what would be a good replacement gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this in `ability.rb`

```
can :manage Fruit do |fruit|
  user.roles.exists?(fruit.id)
end
```

and in your controller you can do

```
def your_action
  @fruit = ...

  authorize! :manage, @fruit

  #  ...
end
```